# How can I figure out why testcafe is so slow in Docker

Tags: docker, testing, automated-tests, integration-testing, testcafe

I run our integration tests using testcafe 23.0 in docker. However, the tests often take a long time to start. I recorded the browser and it seems to take a very long time to do nothing:

https://youtu.be/9W6VosNMbhg

It takes 2 minutes to load the page. However, this is instant on my desktop.

How would I start to figure out this problem?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I figured out that that the testcafe proxy was being slowed down. After some limited success with passing `--no-proxy-server` to chrome, I made the networking in docker more permissive, and that stopped the slowdown.

Comment: what did you do exactly to make it more permissive?

Comment: @thomasJungblut I think I removed restrictive settings I had set up.

Answer (score 0):

You can use command option `-d, --debug-mode #` and docker you can use

`docker logs --follow ContainerName/ContainerID`, you can find how to work docker log [here](http://www.littlebigextra.com/view-docker-container-logs/)

You can find error log because slow you docker container